# Customize select,copy/paste in iPad

Tags: ipad

I am working on eBook App in iPad,And using UIMenuController.And i want to customize select,copy and paste function which default in menu-controller. I am not able to customize that function Please help me out with source code

Thanks
Kunal

Comment: Please add what you want to do and what you've done so far. It would be easier for us to help you in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Deepak.. thanks for response.. actually whenever we tap on any perticular text of TextView and TextField that time we get some option over tap point that is select,select all,copy,paste etc. That is UIMenuController, I just want to customize that option and add another option... like dictionary. Pleas if you can understand then help me if posible.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Derive UITextView as follows.

```
//MyUITextView.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface MyUITextView : UITextView {

}
@end

//MyUITextView.m
#import "MyUITextView.h"
@implementation MyUITextView
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender 
{
    if (action == @selector(menu1:))
        return YES;

    if (action == @selector(menu2:))
        return YES;

    return NO;//[super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}

- (void)menu1:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"in menu1");
}

- (void)menu2:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"in menu2");
}

@end
```

In your view controller under viewDidLoad

```
UIMenuItem *menu1 = [[[UIMenuItem alloc] init]autorelease];
menu1.title = @"MyMenu1";
menu1.action = @selector(menu1:);

UIMenuItem *menu2 = [[[UIMenuItem alloc] init]autorelease];
menu2.title = @"MyMenu2";
menu2.action = @selector(menu2:);

UIMenuController* mc = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
mc.menuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: menu1, menu2, nil];
```

You need to assign class to your TextView from interfacebuilder if it is on nib and if you create it dynamically create object of MyUITextView instead of UITextView.

Above code adds 2 custom menu while you select text and when you select option it will fire selector accordingly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great. I tried reading Apple's documentation, but it's too generic and not very clear how to figure out this particular case. This is a quick recipe.